# Detecting the browser "Save image as..." request in server side

Tags: java, http, browser

**Steps:**

- Right click on any image, for example: http://whsdigitalmedia.weebly.com/uploads/1/3/1/0/13103434/baseball.jpg
- When I click on "Save as image...", a request has been sent to server.

How can I detect "Save image as..." option is used from this request on server side?

**Notes:**

- Creating a "Save" or "Download" link and using it to download the image is not preferable.
- The business needs is preventing the "JavaScript" usages, so I can only use the server side solution(s).
- Same issue of http://www.stucox.com/blog/client-side-vs-server-side-detection-for-webp/#the-save-image-as-problem

[image]

Thanks,

**Mughrabi**

Comment: Without JavaScript, this is impossible. Even with JavaScript, you probably won't be able to create a reliable solution. And even then, there are other ways to download an image (ctrl+s, using the Network tab in a console). Your best bet is to change the image to a CSS background-image so that it cannot be right-clicked. But experienced users will get the image not matter what. Even the worlds largest photo sites can't truly prevent someone from downloading their images. Your last option is to go stock photo style and use watermarks and small previews.

Comment: If I changed the image to CSS background-image, I'll not be able to use it in <img src=""> html tag.

Answer (score -1):

I can't see that you can achieve this without using client side scripting like javascript or one of its frameworks. Once the image is loaded in the browser, it is out of the control of the server. You can only have an idea about user interaction by communicating with the client. To do this You need some sort of script which runs on the browser engine. If you use javascript or one of javascript based frameworks, You can use AJAX call to detect when the button clicked.

Comment: Yes, the business needs is preventing the JavaScript usages, so I can only use the server side as a solution.

Comment: Thanks for highlighting this point, I've updated the question.

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: I think this is popular issue, which Facebook has their experience for this http://www.stucox.com/blog/client-side-vs-server-side-detection-for-webp/#the-save-image-as-problem

Comment: Your link doesn't talk about detecting "Save image as...". It just talks about when Facebook users downloaded a webp image, they couldn't view it locally.

Comment: Thanks for commenting this question. Because webp image is a compressed file and it only works on a little browsers, users that used "Save as image..." are downloading webp image instead of download the original image. I guess facebook is not able to detect the "Save image as..." action from their servers side, so they roll back the project. I faced a similar issue, and I'm afraid to have incomplete project if and only if I did not find a solution for this issue.

Comment: Unless you use some plugins, or application specific thick client implementation, I couldn't see a way  to talk with your server with out the help of some script in ordinary browsers.

Comment: @Yohannes, you can able to communicate the server side if the server side provide "Vary:Accept" in response headers, so I assume the browsers will ask the server about the image for each request.

Comment: Yohannes, Brain I guess this issue is something missing from the browsers itself, I think browsers should provide such information via these kind of operations.

Comment: We are actually in the same page. if browsers made changes to support that feature, that is another story, Or the web application might have its own browser like RICH thick client which has to be installed in the client machine.